# Invoking ejb method with transaction attribute REQUIRES_NEW and execute setRollbackOnly in caller method

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.0, rollback

I have the following two EJB3.0 Beans

```
public class ExternalBean {
      @Resource
      private SessionContext ctx;
      @EJB
      protected DataBaseLogging dbLogger;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doExternaljob() {

    try{
     .....  
    }catch(Exception e){
     logger.log();
     ctx.setRollbackOnly();
     throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DataBaseLogging  {
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void log(){
  //write log data to db
  ......
 }
}
```

Since method log() of EJB DatabaseLogging has transaction attribute REQUIRES_NEW i expected
that if it completed successfully data whould be written to db independent of the outcome of caller method doExternaljob(). But this not what happens. It seems that log() method is also rolled back and no data is written. 
If i remove the call to setRollbackOnly() the data is written correctly. But can i be sure that in this case by throwing an exception the outer transaction is always rolled back?

Is this considered a normal behaviour?

Comment: Is the `logger` vs `dbLogger` just a copy-paste error?  If yes, then it should work (and the setRollbackOnly should not rollback the work done by log).  If no, then how was `logger` obtained?  Is it actually an EJB reference, or was the instance created directly?

Comment: Yes logger and dbLogger is the same. It was a typo. But the behaviour is as presented in the post.